# "To a mouse" by Robert Burns

Tags: poetry

I have been fascinated by a poem of Robert Burns ["To a mouse"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43816/to-a-mouse-56d222ab36e33) from my childhood.
It is amazingly, heart-breakingly translated to my native language.

When reading the origin, very much of the poem charm is, sorrowfully, lost. I don't lose hope to read it in English and get the same trembling I get when reading in translation.

So, I have some questions related to the poem. I could not find good translation for the following phrases / sentences:

> Thou need na start awa sae hasty,

What does *na*, *awa* and *sae* mean? Are these old-style / modified versions of modern English? Are they used to stress something special?

The same questons run for *na* usage in

> I doubt na, whyles, but thou may thieve;

This one is just a jibberish for me:

> ’S a sma’ request:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poem is not written in English, but in Scots - a related but different language. As this isn't about learning English, it isn't a topic for [ell.se].  More generally interpreting poetry is usually better on [literature.se] or [english.se]

Comment: Most non-Scottish English speakers have to look up some of the words in this fine poem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, I think, that this poem, like much of the work of [Burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Burns), is not written in Standard English. It uses many words from Scots Gaelic or the Scottish dialect of English. Indeed many of these words were, I understand, already obsolete or uncommon when Burns used them, but were brought back into more common use by his works.

The [Wikipedia article on the poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse) calls it "a Scots-language poem"
Specifically:

> Thou need na start awa sae hasty,

means

> You need not start away so hastily

or

> You don't need to jump away so quickly

Your next example:

> I doubt na, whyles, but thou may thieve;

means

> I don't doubt that you steal from time to time.

" whyles" is a dialect word related to "while" used often in the fixed phrase "at whyles" meaning "at various times".

> ’S a sma’ request

means simply

> it is a small request

In general "na"="not; "sae"="so"; "awa"="away"; "laith "="lothe"(reluctant); " Wi’"="with"; "bickerin brattle"="argumentative chatter"; "rin ="run"; "maun "="must"; "ane"="one"(the number, not the pronoun); "monie"="Many"; "a'"="all"; "Gang"=go ("Gang thy ways"="go away" or "be about your own business);  "aft"="often;" "agley"="amiss" or "aeey"; "drear"="dreary, bleak"

The best-known line of the poem is almost surely:

> The best laid schemes o’ Mice an’ Men,           Gang aft agley,

which is the source of the title of the Steineck novel and play, *Of  mice and Men*.

Answer (score 1):

Burns's *To A Mouse* is written in [Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language), a form of English spoken in Scotland (opinion varies about whether Scots is a distinct language or a dialect of English). You can get the meanings of Scots words from [DSL here](https://dsl.ac.uk/).

*na* is used for negation, and "need na" means "need not" or "do not need". In Scots, negation is commonly achieved by adding the particle "nocht", "na", "not", "no", or similar after the verb, rather than putting it before the verb as in standard English. See the [DSL website](https://dsl.ac.uk/about-scots/history-of-scots/grammar/) again.

*awa* is just "away".

*sae* is "so".

So "Thou need na start awa sae hasty" means "You don't need to start away so hastily", i.e. "There is no need to run away."

Likewise "I doubt na, whyles, but thou may thieve" means "I do not doubt that sometimes you thieve." "Whyles" is in the dictionary, and this use of "but" means "nevertheless" or "still" (it was also found in older versions of southern English but is now obsolete there).

In "'s a sma' request", "'s" is short for "is" or "it is", and "sma'" for small.

Comment: Try saying that Scots is a dialect of English in a Glasgow pub on a Friday night. You'll soon hear an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Burns) says, Burns was Scottish and wrote poetry in the Scots Language (or a "light Scots dialect" that's slightly less difficult for other English speakers to understand). I'd recommend using the [Dictionaries of the Scots Language](https://dsl.ac.uk/)
("Dictionars o the Scots Leid") to look up words. It can be a little hard to use, but this is what I got:

- Na = not
- Awa = away
- Sae = so
- 'S = not in dictionary but likely "it's"
- Sma' = small

Comment: The [Scottish Government](https://www.gov.scot/publications/scots-language-policy-scots-version/) says: "We are fair blythe tae be eekin on a cuttie innins tae this Scots Language Policy. We, in the Scottish Government, are continuin tae tak important steps tae heize the profile o the Scots leid. This paper sets oot policy commitments an context, oor reasons for supportin Scots, the ettles we hae as a Government an the practical steps we will tak."